# Drupal 7, subpages not showing up

Tags: drupal, menubar, drupal-7

I have pages that I've organised to be under another main page but it isn't showing up under the secondary menu.

How do I get the secondary menu to display child pages of the current page?

Would there be a theme that does this already, i've tried zen and stark but they don't list the pages organised under the current page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a bug that I've run into myself: [Custom menus never receive an active trail](http://drupal.org/node/942782)

I've explained a workaround in a [duplicate issue](http://drupal.org/node/984648).

**To sumerize:**

The problem is that Drupal core active trail, breadcrumb and menu expansion only work for a set of core menus, defined as:

```
$menus = variable_get(
  'menu_default_active_menus',
  array_keys(menu_list_system_menus())
);
```

There is no interface to change this, but you could do it in your settings.php and add the names of the menus you have created. Not a practically solution, but at least it works. You don't usually create new menus that often, so should be fine. An example of what to put in your `settings.php` file:

```
$conf['menu_default_active_menus'] = array(
  'navigation', // Core menu
  'management', // Core menu
  'user-menu', // Core menu
  'main-menu', // Core menu
  'menu-products', // Custom menu
  'menu-custom-menu', // Custom menu
);
```

Comment: whereabouts does the settings.php go?

Comment: I've seen some patches, does this mean I have to patch it in?

Answer (score 0):

The [Menu Block module](https://drupal.org/project/menu_block) works well for displaying the kind of sub-menu you're describing. The module's administration page has lots of options though, so it can take a while to tweak it to get just what you need.